# $\frac{ \log(x^t)}{t}= \log x$ or $0$?

Tags: limits

$\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \log(x^t)/t = \lim\limits_{t \to 0} 
\log((x^t)^{1/t}) = 
\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \log(x) = \log(x)$

$\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \log(x^t)  =0$

$\lim\limits_{t \to 0} t  =0$

$\lim\limits_{t \to 0} t'  = \lim\limits_{t \to 0} 1 =1$ (Please note that this is not zero.)

Using L'Hôpital's rule, we get:

$\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \log(x^t)/t =\lim\limits_{t \to 0} t(x^{t-1})/x^t$

$=\lim\limits_{t \to 0} t(x^{t-1})/x^t$

$=\lim\limits_{t \to 0} t/x$

$=0$

How can the same limit have 2 different answers?
I understand there is a mistake in my second approach, but I can't find it.

Comment: The derivation must be made with respect to the variabile that is varying in the limit... in your case $t$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You differentiated the numerator with respect to $x$ and you differentiated the denominator with respect to $t$.  You are supposed to differentiate both sides with respect to $t$.

To differentiate $\log (x^{t})$ with respect to $t$, put in $\log (x^{t}) = t \log (x)$ and take the derivative with respect to $t$, with $x$ as an independent variable.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know what mistake I made! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You probably wouldn't have made the same mistake with
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\log(2^t)}{t}
$$
which is a particular case of your limit (for $x=2$). Applying l’Hôpital would give
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\dfrac{1}{2^t}\cdot2^t\log2}{1}=\log2
$$
Now just replace $2$ with $x$.

However, applying l’Hôpital is overkill, because $\log(x^t)=t\log x$, so your function is constant (for $t\ne0$):
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\log(x^t)}{t}=
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t\log x}{t}=
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\log x}{1}=\log x
$$